# The unit/location where I did my military duty

Tags: word-request

I was conscripted in the Bundeswehr. ("Allgemeiner Wehrdienst"/"Grundwehrdienst", 9 months of duty that, once you passed the health check, could be avoided only by doing civil service).

How would I describe in which unit/location I was during that time? A friend wrote in his CV that he was "posted at the Tank School in Munster".

Is "posted" correct? First, I only heard that word in connection with online message boards, and second, LEO translation knows "posting", but the German word given ("Abkommandierung") is used not for the barracks/ship where you are normally doing your duty, but only if, for some time, you have to go elsewhere for a limited timespan, expecting to return to your "default" barracks afterwards (e.g. going to Berlin to work with a Ministry's group, or if you are going to Kosovo or Afghanistan)

Comment: To argue that the word "post" is possible, here is one definition of the verb **[post](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/post_2)**: "2 [transitive] to send someone to a place to guard it or to watch who arrives and leaves. *Extra guards were posted at the border.*" (See also: sense 2a.)

Comment: While I have a good answer regarding U.S. English, could a British native please acknowledge that these words are also understood on the Isles?

Answer (score 3):

In the U.S., you would use *stationed at* to describe your home base, and *deployed to* to describe a time of more limited service, particularly in an area that doesn't have permanent facilities:

> *I was stationed at the Tank School in Munster before being deployed to Kosovo*.

If the limited service stint is in a city rather than a combat region, the U.S. military will use *temporary duty*:

> *I was stationed at the Tank School in Munster, during which time I served a two-month temporary duty assignment in Berlin*.

Comment: If I understand the OP correctly, his friend is in Germany, so *post* should be possible. I posted a related definition of *post* to the OP above. I hope you will agree with me.

Comment: If we are looking for a word that refers to a deployment (not to the home base where one is stationed) then we want "deployed to" or "posted *to*"  ( not "posted *at*").  The verb "post" is analogous to the verb "sent".